# Oauth2 Ruby [Autenticación falla]

Tags: api, ruby, oauth2

estoy intentando conectarme a una API que usa Oauth2, y necesito pasarle un code, pero no sé cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
require "oauth2"

# Create the client with your credentials
UID = "XXXX"
SECRET = "XXXX"
client = OAuth2::Client.new(UID, SECRET, site: "https://XXXX")


# Token credentials
redirect_uri = "https://XXXX/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ftools.html&response_type=code"
token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', redirect_uri: redirect_uri, headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json' })

puts token
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente,

```
invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client. (OAuth2::Error)
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algunas cosas me parecen raras en tu implementación, lo primero:

```
redirect_uri = "https://XXXX/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ftools.html&response_type=code"
```

Esta url debería ser la que tengas configurada **en tu servicio de OAuth** donde él pueda redirigir luego de haberte autenticado correctamente. Punto aparte, me parece raro que tengas `&redirect_uri=http...` dentro de la misma url de redirección.

Otra es que no veo que hayas agregado el código que te permita obtener el valor de `authorization_code_value`. Siguiendo la lógica de tu código, debería ser algo como:

```
client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
```

aunque esto podría variar dependiendo de tu servicio de autenticación ya que podría requerir parámetros adicionales. El resultado de esto será un string con una url a la cual el usuario accederá, luego se autenticará para finalmente redirigir al usuario al `redirect_uri` que le tengas configurado con el valor de `authorization_code_value` como parámetro del request. Con este valor podrás llamar a `client.auth_code.get_token` y completar el proceso de autenticación.

Vale mencionar que ciertos servicios de OAuth, al iniciar sesión como cliente con `OAuth2::Client.new`, no solo requieren que le pases un `site`, sino tambien un `authorize_url` o `token_url`, pero insisto que esto solo dependerá de los requisitos de tu proveedor de OAuth.